# Meterpreter:execute command failed

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

When run `execute -f cmd.exe -i -H`, Meterpreter gave me an error:

> [-] stdapi_sys_process_execute: Operation failed: 1

What is causing this, and how to resolve it?

Comment: this is a software-specific error question and not an InfoSec question - a Metasploit forum would be a better place to ask

Comment: @schroeder The Metasploit forum is in migration right now so it would be better if we deal it here. What is the meterpreter version (Win, PHP, Java etc)? I believe you are launching cmd.exe from a non native meterpreter version running in a sandbox or low integrity process.

Comment: @void_in this question is simply not on-topic here - we aren't product support for metasploit

Comment: @schroeder I understand what you are saying but this closing of questions based upon off-topic is too inconsistent. To give you an example, go to http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=metasploit and look at all the questions. Every one of them is asking about Metasploit help just as this question. At the end of the day every question is about some kind of a product.

Comment: @void_in questions about product is not the issue - troubleshooting errors in a product is out of scope.